# Error when connecting via Windows Remote Management

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I have a simple PowerShell script that uses `Invoke-Command` to invoke a PowerShell `ScriptBlock` on a remote computer through Windows Remote Management (WinRM). The script is being executed from a Windows Server 2012 system, and targeting a Windows 8.1 system.

The script is very simple, and looks something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName client03 -ScriptBlock { Get-Process; };
```

Here is the error:

```
[client03] Connecting to remote server client03 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown
security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (client03:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108387,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Furthermore, when I try to connect to the remote computer's administrative network shares, I'm seeing the following error message: "*The target account name is incorrect.*"

[image: Error Message]

When I try to connect to the computer's administrative share in a local session, I get the error: "*The specified network name is no longer available.*"

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the target computer had recently been rebuilt, and it had a temporary computer name. There was still an old DNS entry for the computer, so connecting to the computer using the old name resulted in an error "*The target account name is incorrect.*"

After renaming the computer, and referring to the computer using its correct name, the problem disappeared. Alternatively, connecting to the computer using its IP address was successful.

[image: Computer Name]